# How to mock react-native module (not 3rd party module) with jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am trying to mock a module that ships with react-native ***(not 3rd party modules)***, such as `LayoutAnimation`:

```js
import * as RN from 'react-native'

RN.LayoutAnimation = jest.fn()
```

But the test fails with:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'decelerationRate' of undefined

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/WebView/WebView.ios.js:555:3254)
  at Object.get WebView [as WebView] (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js:73:22)
```

Is there any other way to mock/stub out a RN module such as `LayoutAnimation` or any other react-native (not 3rd party) module?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to simply do `jest.mock('LayoutAnimation');`

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Do you mind sharing how this works? Is Jest aware of the react-native API?

Comment: In your file package.json you have this : `"jest": { "preset": "react-native"}`. So yes, jest is aware of react-native API

Answer (score 0):

You got this message because of line №217 in /node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/WebView/WebView.ios.js

```
decelerationRate: ScrollView.propTypes.decelerationRate
```

Because ScrollView is mocked ScrollView.propTypes === undefined

I solved this issue by adding:

```js
import {PropTypes} from 'react';
ScrollView.propTypes = { decelerationRate: PropTypes.number };
```

to setup script file (file which set by setupTestFrameworkScriptFile property in jest section of package.json);